# Why does OpenGL allow/use fractional values as the location of vertices?

Tags: opengl

As far as I understand, location of a point/pixel cannot be a fraction, at least on a raster graphics system where hardwares use pixels to display images.

Then, why and how does OpenGL use fractional values for plotting pixels?

For example, how is it possible: `glVertex2f(0.15f, 0.51f);` ?

Comment: I see you've edited your question to remove the third coordinate from the call. It actually makes no difference - the third coordinate is still there, only in this case it defaults to 0.

Comment: It seems that you didn't even try to read any tutorial or wiki on opengl, -1

Comment: @BROY nothing. I just explained my downvote.

Comment: @BROY: The point lisyarus tries to make is, that asking uninformed questions may be taken as an insult to the people who are capable of answering the questions. The reason is, that many questions can be easily answered by using some search engine or just reading some documentation (the OpenGL specification is publicly available) and doing some reflection (=thinking) about it. StackOverflow *is not* a human powered search engine, so please don't use it like such. I've looked through your question history and while many of them are actually good questions, they'd be better answered using Google.

Answer (score 6):

This command does not plot any pixels. It merely defines the location of a point in 3D space (you'll notice that there are 3 coordinates, while for a pixel on the screen you'd only need 2). This is the starting point for the OpenGL pipeline. This point then goes through a lot of transformations before it ends up on the screen.

Also, the coordinates are unitless. For example, you can say that your viewport is between 0.0f and 1.0f, then these coordinates make a lot of sense. Basically you have to think of these point in terms of mathematics, not pixels.

I would suggest some reading on how OpenGL transformations work, for example [here](https://open.gl/transformations), [here](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) or the tutorial [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

Comment: This is correct, but even after transformation, it is still useful to pass fractional coordinates into the rasterizer.  This is because even though pixels are at integer (or integer + 0.5) locations, the rasterizer-invoked pixel/fragment shaders can utilize [multi-sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing) or even analytical coverage to produce different results depending on the fractional coverage of a primitive over a pixel.

Comment: @MooseBoys Completely true. And this is not limited to 3D graphics either. For example [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) or WPF use the same technique.

Answer (score 2):

The vectors you pass into OpenGL are not viewport positions but *arbitrary* numbers in *some* vector space. Only after a chain of transformations these numbers are mapped into viewport pixel positions. With the old fixed function pipeline this could be anything that can be represented by a vector–matrix multiplication.

These days, where everything is programmable (shaders) the mapping can very well be any kind of function you can think of. For example the values you pass into glVertex (immediate mode call, but available to shaders with OpenGL-2.1) may be interpreted as polar coordinates in the vertex shader:

This is a perfectly valid OpenGL-2.1 vertex shader that interprets the vertex position to be in polar coordinates. Note that due to triangles and lines being straight edges and polar coordinates being curvilinear this gives good visual results only for points or highly tesselated primitives.

```
#version 110

void main() {
    gl_Position =
          gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix
        * vec4( gl_Vertex.y*vec2(sin(gl_Vertex.x),cos(gl_Vertex.x)) , 0, 1);
}
```

As you can see here the valus passed to glVertex are actually arbitrary, unitless components of vectors in some vector space. Only by applying some transformation to the viewport space these vectors gain meaning. Hence it makes no way to impose a certain value range onto the values that go into the vertex attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, before glVertex2f(0.15f, 0.51f) is on the screen, there are many transforms to be done. Making complex thing crudely simpler, after moving your vertex to view space (applying camera position and direction), the magic here is (1) projection matrix, and (2) viewport setting.

Internally, OpenGL "screen coordinates" are in a cube (-1, -1, -1) - (1, 1, 1), :

http://www.matrix44.net/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ogl_coord_object_space_cube.png

Projection matrix 'squeezes' the frustum in this cube (which you do in vertex shader), assuming you have perspective transform - if projection is orthogonal, the projection is just a tube, limited by near and far values (and like in both cases, scaling factors):

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_projectionmatrix01.png

EDIT: Maybe better example here:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#The_Projection_matrix

(EDIT: The Z-coordinate is used as depth value) When fragments are finally transferred to pixels on texture/framebuffer/screen, these are multiplied with viewport settings:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/images/GL_2DViewportAspectRatio.png

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Vertex and pixel are very different things.

It's quite possible to have all your vertices within one pixel (although in this case you probably need help with LODing).

You might want to start here...
http://www.glprogramming.com/blue/ch01.html

Specifically...

> Primitives are defined by a group of one or more vertices. A vertex defines a point, an endpoint of a line, or a corner of a polygon where two edges meet. Data (consisting of vertex coordinates, colors, normals, texture coordinates, and edge flags) is associated with a vertex, and each vertex and its associated data are processed independently, in order, and in the same way.

And...

> Rasterization produces a series of frame buffer addresses and associated values using a two-dimensional description of a point, line segment, or polygon. Each fragment so produced is fed into the last stage, per-fragment operations, which performs the final operations on the data before it's stored as pixels in the frame buffer.